# Getting selected item from Datagrid Combobox Cell

Tags: wpf, vb.net, data-binding, combobox, datagrid

I've been trying to get a selected item from a combobox in a datagrid cell. I have an datagrid which contains several comboboxes which are bound with `ObservableCollection`. So, the code in my WPF look like this:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DgvEmployee" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name" Width="*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox x:Name="cboxName" ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeeName}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Department" Width="*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeeDept}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
       </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

And in my Class:

```
    Dim comboBoxLoad As New ObservableCollection(Of ClcomboboxBinding)

    comboBoxLoad.Add(New ClcomboboxEmployee)
    DataContext = comboBoxLoad
```

My Class `ClcomboboxEmployee` populates `EmployeeName` and `EmployeeDept` from DB. So, it's working fine. Now I want to save from the comboboxes depending what user select. Now,

1. How can I get the selected item from each combobox and save in a Class(`dummyClass`) object String(`SelectedEmployeeName`, `SelectedEmployeeDept`).
2. I've tried something like this after searching for right solution what I really want, most of the solutions are for datagridview, not datagrid:

`Dim seletedCB = DgvEmployee.Columns(1).GetCellContent(DgvEmployee.Items(0)) MsgBox(seletedCB.ToString())`

But it's giving me output as `System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter`.
I also have checked with debugging `selectedCB` doesn't contain selecteditem. What am I doing wrong? How can I achieve the selected item?

I am really stuck here. Your contribution would be life saving. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You should bind selectedvalue to whatever the target property is. Where the value gies to. And.  You should set selectedvaluepath to a string defining the path to the property the value is to come from. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26347.wpf-combobox-binding-in-datagrid.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot. As I am new to the Binding concept, I still am a bit confused. I read the article and also searched about selectedvalue and path. As far as I understood: If I want to save the selected item to a Class(Let's say ```dummyClass```) which has a string ```selectedEmployeeName```, ```selectedEmployeeDept```. Then in my WPF in combobox definition should be like this: ```<ComboBox x:Name="cboxName" ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeeName}" SelectedValue = {Binding dummyClass} SelectedValuePath="selectedEmployeeName"/>``` And same for Dept. Am I right? @Andy